# How to get old state in ngrx, need to revert code of any failure occur

Tags: angular, angular8, ngrx, ngrx-store

Example: let user is on page 5 and user click on next page and that api call fails, then I have to revert to page 5 back with all filter selection remain same. And show the data to user

Answer (score 1):

you need to have an effect for the page request. Its action should have the page number. for example `loadPage({page: 6})`.
Then you need to catch an error in `this.http.get().pipe`. And because you know requested page you can dispatch an action to load page 5 again.

```js
this.http.get().pipe(
  catchError(() => of(loadPage({page: page -1}))), // <- page var should be available from the parent context of the effect.
)
```

Don't forget to cover case when page is 0 or -1, maybe you want simply fail and to display an error message to the user.